# One WCF service, multiple endpoints, different context per endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf, autofac, multi-tenant

I'm writing a multi-tenant WCF application. I've got one "general" service class that is responsible for executing some business logic. I'd like to configure WCF with Autofac in this way that each endpoint will receive different configuration params using custom configuration section e.g.:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="MyApiService">
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:80000" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
      <endpoint name="Tenant1" address="tenant1" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IMyApiService" />
      <endpoint name="Tenant2" address="tenant2" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IMyApiService" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
<apiConfigurationSection>
  <service name="Tenant1" wcfServiceName="MyApiService" param1="value1" param2="value2" />
  <service name="Tenant2" wcfServiceName="MyApiService" param1="value3" param2="value4" />
</apiConfigurationSection>
```

I'd like parameters `param1` and `param` to be injected as a contex when matching service (by URL) is called.

Could you suggest me any solution how to do this?

Comment: If your service does different things depending on the way that it is exposed, then I think you should do 2 wrapers of your service. Keep the service logic separated and create 2 envelopes that have the behaviour your need for `param1` and `param2 `, and call the service inside.